# Mapping of XML data to/from a java object(s) using Dozer

Tags: java, xml, dozer, cxml

Test mapping of XML data to/from a java object(s) using dozer.

That is, given a sample XML file , map this to new java classes with appropriate get/set methods for the various elements

A sample XML file is given below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<cXML payloadID="1272549644772.1050674118.000000197@2Vmg9c/TnwT1ZqGdAuiHQvbDmNc=" timestamp="2010-04-29T07:00:44-07:00" version="1.2.020">
        <Header>
                <From>
                        <Credential domain="Test_Code">
                                <Identity>ID_SYSTEM</Identity>
                        </Credential>
                </From>
                <To>
                        <Credential domain="Test_Code">
                                <Identity>ID_SYSTEM</Identity>
                        </Credential>
                </To>
                <Sender>
                        <Credential domain="AribaNetworkUserId">
                                <Identity>test.test@sial.com</Identity>
                                <SharedSecret>sigma123</SharedSecret>
                        </Credential>
                        <UserAgent>Sender Application 1.0</UserAgent>
                </Sender>
        </Header>
</cXML>
```

I need to map this to new java class

Please help me.

Comment: what did you tried? If both classes are same `dozer` map them auto...

Comment: @jordi I didnt tried anything. I searched , but I was not able to find any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic `dozer` mapping is really easy, if the attributes have same name / type it will map auto:

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>org.dozer.vo.TestObject</class-a>
    <class-b>org.dozer.vo.TestObjectPrime</class-b>
</mapping>
```

If you have some different named attributes:

```
<mapping> 
    <class-a>org.dozer.vo.TestObject</class-a>
    <class-b>org.dozer.vo.TestObjectPrime</class-b>   
    <field>
      <a>one</a>
      <b>onePrime</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```

For more info you can find in [the user guide](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/dozer-user-guide.pdf) and examples of [XML mappings](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/mappings.html)

Answer (score 0):

sample dozerMapping.xml file.

http://dozer.sourceforge.net/schema/beanmapping.xsd">

```
<mapping map-id="a">
    <class-a>com.java.beans.Employee</class-a>
    <class-b>com.java.beans.Address</class-b>
    <field>
        <a>streetNumber</a>
        <b>streetNumber</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>city</a>
        <b>city</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>state</a>
        <b>state</b>
    </field>
    <field>
        <a>country</a>
        <b>country</b>
    </field>
</mapping>
```